# IIS: Content-Length 0 for CSS, Javascript and Images

Tags: iis, iis-7

After a clean re-installation of my Windows 7 system, I can't get IIS 7 to properly deliver any static content. Dynmic content (ASPX pages and content served by ASP.NET MVC  controllers) works fine, but static files such as CSS, Javascript and Images give me a 200 OK status code and a Content-Length of 0.

The problem occurs with all web sites on my server, even a brandnew ASP:NET MVC template project with no changes. It also occurs with both Firefox and IE 8.

What could possibly be the problem?

Note that I also installed the latest Windows Azure SDK, perhaps that messed up some settings. But I don't know how to proceed with for troubleshooting this.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Check your "Windows Features" for

> Internet Information Services > WWW Services > Common HTTP Features > Static Content

[image: IIS HTTP static content]

Comment: Yesss! Thank you so much. It looks so obvious once I know about this. I wonder why it wasn't checked by default in the first place :-)

Comment: Monday morning, and this saved my day!

Comment: This is halarious. So customizable and with such sensible defaults.